# Is there a way to install the Android firmware into a iPhone?

Tags: stock-android, ios

I want to turn a iPhone in to a Android OS phone.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any available because the runtime as well as the hardware with Android OS and iOS is different.